DOS calculation with QE
I am doing a DOS calculation via QE and the following is my SCF file :
<I'll add it later>
My nscf file :
<I'll add it later>
My DOS file:
<I'll add it later>
My SLURM submission script:
<I'll add it later>
Can you please help me why it is giving the following error?
    Error in routine dos (1):
     reading dos namelist

The problem is in the DOS step, because for scf and nscf it is working.

Could you add the code inside a code block instead as an image?

The problem is in your dos input file. Try changing emin to Emin and emax to Emax. Also, set outdir="./outdir" explicitly in the input file. Lastly, keep an empty line at the end of the file after /.

+1 but please also make your title more specific and clear.
